# Using Bootstrap 5 in Angular 14 with SCSS

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to setup Bootstrap 5 in my Angular 14 project which is using SCSS instead of CSS. I have installed bootstrap via npm (`npm install bootstrap --save`) and it's now correctly referenced in my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

I've added the boostrap.scss file reference in my angular.json file:

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/file-sharing-app.ui",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/custom-theme.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
```

But the below class is having no effect:

```
<span class="ml-3">File Sharing App</span>
```

None of the other bootstrap classes I've used have worked either. I have tried restarting the application (re running `ng serve`). Does anybody know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SCSS, don't add it to your angular.json config. Instead, add this to your `scr/styles.scss` directly:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Comment: So I removed  the bootstrap line from angular.json file and added the line above to the top of my style.scss file but this hasn't made any difference (i.e. the bootstrap classes still aren't working as described in the op)

Comment: @Pablo52, can you describe which bootstrap classes aren't working? Because I don't believe `ml-3` is a valid class name in Bootstrap 5.

Comment: But where is the styles.scss directly ?

Comment: @SirajAli in `scr/styles.scss`

Comment: @g0rb yes, but i was select css stylesheet during installation ,, thanks for positive reply

Answer (score -6):

Have you tried rerunning your applications?

If you already tried that, then you can try installing jquery

```
npm install jquery --save
```

and adding

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

Comment: jQuery is not required for Bootstrap 5